# Deploying Existing Spring Boot Application on Google App Engine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-boot

I have developed an application using Spring locally. I want to deploy my existing application using Google App Engine. Does anyone know how to deploy existing application to GAE?

Comment: Have you tried the answer below, specially the update?

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez I did and it works! Thanks!

Comment: Accept the answer please :-)

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez my bad. Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your project using Cloud Tools for Eclipse. Go to [this page](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/google-cloud-tools-eclipse) and drag and drop the 'install' icon inside your Eclipse installation. See the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart) on how to use the plugin.

Basically you right click on you project and convert it to a maven project, or choose `File > Import... > Existing Maven Projects` wizard. Once you have your maven project loaded into Eclipse, tight click again and `Configure > Convert to App Engine Project`. [This guide](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/converting) explains the whole process.

Finally, having your project set up:

> **To deploy the project to App Engine Standard environment:**
>
> 1. Right click the project in the Package Explorer the project to open
>      the context menu.
> 2. Select Deploy to App Engine Standard
> 3. A dialog pops up.
> 4. Select the account you want to deploy with, or add a new account.
> 5. The list of projects the account has access to loads. Select the one
>      you want to deploy to.
> 6. Click OK.

All the details are [here](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/deploying).

### UPDATE:

In this [Github repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard#steps-to-convert-a-spring-boot-application-for-app-engine-standard), there are instructions on how to convert an existing Spring Boot App to Google App Engine. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48261777/9015852), I apply those instructions to a sample application.