# Google App Engine Standard env - not found controller method - Spring Boot app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot

I was trying to deploy Spring Boot application on Google App Engine (standard environment). At first I cloned example app from this nice tutorial https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-web-application-part-4-spring-mvc/

For example I called http://localhost:8080/products and template with data was displayed.

So everything ran without problems, I was able to call all controller methods locally. Then I decided as experiment to deploy it on GAE. I adjusted pom.xml according to instructions from here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard

It means I excluded Tomcat dependency, changed packaging from jar to war, created appengine-web.xml file etc. As next step, I created GAE project in GAE console and copied APP ID into appengine-web.xml. Then I ran mvn clean package and war was created in target folder. Finally I started with GAE deployment and it also went smoothly without errors.

My app is now deployed on this URL https://20180109t135551-dot-oe-gae-test.appspot.com/

If you try it, you will see Hello World in browser. But if I try to call /products controller method like this https://20180109t135551-dot-oe-gae-test.appspot.com/products I get "not found" error.

Can you give me advice on which URL should I call my controller methods? Did I forget to implement something like web.xml servlet mapping? Or is it some specific Spring Boot - Google App Engine problem?

I will be grateful for any hint.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Go to stackdriver and see the logs so we can know what errors you're receiving: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview

Comment: method:  "GET"   
  requestId:  "5a551d2d00ff08353d5200ffd1dd0001687e6f652d6761652d746573740001323031383031303974313335353531000100"   
  resource:  "/products"   
  startTime:  "2018-01-09T19:51:09.537917Z"   
  status:  404   
  traceId:  "680d8d917491ccbe61c6e72c87dc2c0c"   
  userAgent:  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"   
  versionId:  "20180109t135551"

Comment: Sorry for the format of the pasted log. Simply, it is 404 not found for /products resource

Comment: I downloaded the app and I was able to deploy it. I can see the products page. Let's find out what the differences between our projects are

Comment: Great ! And how could we compare our source codes?

Comment: I will send you mine with a link. If it works, I will post the steps as an answer

Comment: you can send it to oliver.eder123@gmail.com Thanks :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I added the procedure, which is basically what the links says applied to the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [this steps](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard#steps-to-convert-a-spring-boot-application-for-app-engine-standard) translates into the following for [the code](https://github.com/springframeworkguru/springbootwebapp/tree/part4):

1. In pom.xml, change `<packaging>jar</packaging>`  to  `<packaging>war</packaging>`
2. In the package `guru.springframework` add this class:

Code:

```
package guru.springframework;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

3. Remove Tomcat Starter:

Find this dependency in the POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And add these lines:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

4. Exclude Jetty dependencies and include the Servlet API dependency:

   `<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>`
5. Add the App Engine Standard plugin:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
       <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.1</version>
   </plugin>
   ```

   6. Add a file called `appengine-web.xml` in `src/webapp/WEB-INF` with these contents:

   `<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
       <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
       <runtime>java8</runtime>
       </system-properties>
   </appengine-web-app>`

   7. Exclude JUL to SLF4J Bridge by locating this dependency in the pom:

   `<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>`

and modifying it this way:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

8. Avoiding out of memory errors:

In `src/main/resources` add a  logging.properties file with:

```
.level = INFO
```

and inside `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml` paste this:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties" />
</system-properties>
```

**EDIT:**

For steps `3` and `7` you can also go to the project explorer (in case you're using Eclipse) and navigate to **Libraries -> Maven dependencies** and select each library individually (`jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25` and `spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.3.RELEASE` in my case). Right click on each library and go to **Maven -> Exclude Maven artifact**... And click **Ok**. This will have the same effect on the POM as editing.